# Memoize class instance until one of its methods throws

Tags: python, decorator

I have several different classes that are relatively expensive to instantiate and their methods work fine until one of them throws and at that point there's no point in keeping the object around since the state is messed up in some way.

I would usually just memoize a function that instantiates the object, but that won't work in this case since the memoize decorator only knows about the object at instantiation time, it doesn't know about each of the method calls.

How might I solve this problem? Is it possible to create a decorator that wraps all of the methods individually and instantiates a new object when one of them throws?

Comment: are these caught or uncaught?

Comment: Sometimes they are caught, sometimes uncaught. I definitely want that to be up to the caller. The key here is that object that the method is called on should be used again if the last call didn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `dir(cls)` to get all the stuff on it and apply a try except decorator to each item in there that is callable ...  then when you catch an exception set a flag on the class (valid=False) and then raise the error ... then memoize checks that flag before returning ... if there is no flag just return...

at least thats the only way i can think of doing it...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your memoizer has an inner function like:

```
def memocall(function, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return cache[(args, kwargs)]
    except KeyError:
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        cache[(args, kwargs)] = result
        return result
```

Change that slightly to be like:

```
def memocall(function, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return cache[(args, kwargs)]
    except KeyError:
        try: 
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            cache = {}  # Clear the cache
            raise       # Re-throw the exception
        cache[(args, kwargs)] = result
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "._valid" attribute to the instances, and before returning it from the cache you can check if it's true. And if it isn't treat it as a cache miss.